# JasperReports for grails: Using HashMap as Model?

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

Imagine I have two classes in Groovy that look like that:

```
class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
}

class Item {
  int id;
  int price;
}
```

Now it would be simple to create a JasperReport listing all persons' names using the following SQL:

```
SELECT name FROM Person
```

Also, it would be easy to pass a Model from which the list should be created:

```
def p = Person.withCriteria {
   eq('name','SomeGuy')
}
chain(controller:'jasper',action:'index',model:[data:p],params:params)
```

But what I want to do is to use the following query:

```
SELECT name, (SELECT sum(i.price) FROM Item f WHERE f.id=p.id) as priceSum FROM Person p
```

And now this is the part where I don't know how to go on: How can I pass any Model to the jasperReport? I can't just use

```
def p = Person.withCriteria {
   eq('name','SomeGuy')
}
```

because then, the priceSum attribute would be missing. 
What I would like to do is something like this:

```
def l = ['name':'SomeGuy','priceSum':'5000']
chain(controller:'jasper',action:'index',model:[data:l],params:params)
```

But this doesn't work either, it gives me:

```
 Message: Cannot get property 'name' on null object 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
```

Is there anything simliar to this that would work?

Comment: Have you tried passing a list of maps, rather than a map alone? `def l = [ ['name':'SomeGuy','priceSum':'5000'] ]`